# Should i add index on very small mongodb objects?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with ~ 100k rows of very small objects - 3 fields of integers values and 3 dateTime.
The queries will be on 3 fields - around 3/sec.
How much benefit do i get for adding indexes on those fields? 
Is it something that should be consider about or should i just add indexes on all heavily used queries ? 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try just adding the indexes and retry? That will give you the answer.

Comment: Good point, but that will just answer me for the specific case. i was wondering if there is any rule of thumb

Comment: If you will open this query as an api to consumers, 3 seconds is not acceptable. It requires index.